# How to correctly setup spark fair scheduler and pools?

Tags: apache-spark

I am running a simple spark app test, which reads one year of data and writes the same amount of data to Hive, partitioned by day. Before writing I coalesce to 15 partitions each file, in order to not have many small files written.
I would like to do this in parallel using FAIR scheduler; my application is running with 200 executors and 4 cores (which means 800 task at a time can run) and this is the configuration of the pool

```
<allocations>
  <pool name="writing_pool">
    <schedulingMode>FAIR</schedulingMode>
    <minShare>400</minShare>
  </pool>
</allocations
```

The idea is to write 10 days of data per job

```
dates.grouped(10).toSeq.par.foreach(s => {

  spark.sparkContext.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool", "writing_pool")

  print("submitting writes for " + s.mkString(","))

  val toBeInserted = dataWithDate
    .where(col("yyyy_mm_dd").isin(s:_*))

  toBeInserted.coalesce(15).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .insertInto("test_write_buffer_parallel_hive")
})
```

I do not know why, but my cluster is not fully used, for example
[image: spark UI]

As you can see, at this moment 38 tasks only at running, while I have 200x4 slots available. Do you know why is that?

Comment: Maybe you've got only 38 files on input... Or 1 HDFS file spanning 38 logical blocks?

Comment: No, I get many more files in input (around a thousand partitions)